# strcopy implementation possible mistakes

Tags: c, string

I have written a string copy and concatenation implementation.

```
int mycopy(char *a,char *b)
{   
    for(int i=0;b[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        a[i]=b[i];    
    }
    b[i]='\0';    
    return 0;
}

int concat(char *b,char *c)
{    
    int i=0,j=0;

    for(i=0;b[i]!='\0';i++);

    for(j=0;c[j]!='\0';j++)
    {    
        b[j+i]=c[j];   
    }    
    b[j+i]='\0';
    return 0;
}
```

Even though it works for me for various inputs, what could be the apparent problems one could run into while  using these snippets?

Comment: Could you please indent your code and fix your white space?

Comment: Some coding style nitpicks: In the first function you declare and initialize `i` inside the for-statement, in the second at the start of the function. Best to stick to one system for readability (the second way is more compatible with different C standards). In the second function, no need to initialize them to `0`, you are doing that in the loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mycopy seems to have a bug:  it loops over b until it finds \0 and copies the contents to a, but at the end, it adds \0 to b instead of to a, so it leaves a non zero-terminated.

Apart from that, if you call this function with b pointing to non zero-terminated string (for example, if b was not initialized prior to the call), it will crash. It will also crash if a wasn't allocated enough memory (at least strlen(b), because you don't add \0 to it :) ) to hold the contents of b.

concat has similar problems: it will crash if b or c don't point to zero-terminated strings or if b doesn't point to memory chunk of length at least strlen(c) + strlen(b)+1.

Also, returning 0 isn't very informative: I would rather return either the length of the copied string or the pointer to the copied / concatenated string (the last is what [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) and [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) do).

Comment: It should be pointed out that the standard `strcpy()` and `strcat()` functions have the same problems regarding passing in arguments that aren't valid strings or destination buffers that aren't large enough.

Comment: First point is *crucial*, well spotted. I'd throw in NULL checks as well for each string. Would declaring `a` in the first and `c` in the second function as `const` help the compiler spot some errors?

Comment: It definitely helps to declare as const the arguments which should not be modified.